# react-places-autocomplete restrictions

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, autocomplete

I just started using [react-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/kenny-hibino/react-places-autocomplete) library and I can not find how to restrict predictions to a specified country.

I am able to find it for google maps autocomplete [ComponentRestrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions) but not for the *react-places-autocomplete* library

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12):

//just use

```
 <PlacesAutocomplete
    searchOptions={searchOptions}
```

//and add a const

```
const searchOptions = {
  componentRestrictions: { country: ['us'] },
  types: ['city']
}
```

Comment: this still shows results from other countries

Comment: @Muath_01 i'm using react-google-places-autocomplete with autocompletionRequest={{ componentRestrictions: { ['fr'] } }}

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict your results with [`option`](https://github.com/kenny-hibino/react-places-autocomplete#options) prop.

*From docs;*

> **options**
>
> ```
> Type: Object Required: false Default: {}
> ```
>
> You can fine-tune the settings passed to the AutocompleteService class
>   with options prop. This prop accepts an object following the same
>   format as [`google.maps.places.AutocompletionRequest`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletionRequest) (except for input,
>   which comes from the value of the input field).

```
// these options will bias the autocomplete predictions toward Sydney, Australia with a radius of 2000 meters,
// and limit the results to addresses only
const options = {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 151),
  radius: 2000,
  types: ['address']
}

<PlacesAutocomplete
  inputProps={inputProps}
  options={options}
/>
```

Comment: I saw that, It's not what I need tho. I mean setting that option does not restrict predictions to an specified country, it just does to a radius from a specific coordinate.

Comment: It is what you are looking for. The option prop can contain [`componentRestrictions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions) from `google.maps.places.AutocompletionRequest`. Check the link provided in answer please.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I was trying it without using `{}` so I thought it wasn't it. Sorry and thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it, from the docs

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  autocompletionRequest={{
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: ['us', 'ca'],
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Autocomplete
 options={{
    types: ["(regions)"],
    componentRestrictions: { country: "ru" },
  }}
/>
```